# WCF using 2 Authentication Methods With Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: wcf, authentication, wif

I'm working on a WCF project that will be our new service layer.

These services will be called by 2 separate clients, the first of which is a WPF application and the other is an ASP.Net web application. The WPF client will be run by internal users and will authenticate with the service via domain authentication and run under the context of that user. The other will be used by external users and needs to authenticate using some separate mechanism then impersonate a "WebUser" account on our domain.

I'm reading a bit about Windows Identity Foundation and it sounds like this might be a good fit. Am I right in thinking I could have 2 token services, one for domain authentication and one for something like ASP.Net membership authentication (Or some similar equivalent) and have each client get it's token from the relevant STS and pass that along to the WCF service?

I'm assuming there is an STS I can use out of the box for domain authentication, but will I have to implement the second one myself to authenticate web users? I can't find a lot of information on this.

Am I thinking along the right lines or should I just be creating duel endpoints for each service each with a different authentication mechanism? Or should I be doing something completely different?

Thanks

Comment: Do you wish to be able to make authorisation decisions based on properties of the particular web user? Or are all web users equal? (now and most likely also in the future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big advantage of using Claims-Based authentication / WIF is that both the task of authenticating the user AND the administration of the user's properties are moved way from the applications to the STS/Identity provider.

You are developing a service layer but the true benefits of using WIF will be for the applications written on top of your layer. The WPF application will no longer need to connect to the AD and fetch the user's groups to figure out what they are allowed to do. The groups will already be visible as claims in the token the user/WIF provides.

The web application (is it just one web application or more?) will no longer need the ASP.Net Membership database with accompanying user administration. This functionality gets moved to the STS.

There is a cost. (There always is, somehow...) Claims-Based authentication has a rather steep learning curve. It takes a while for the quarter to drop for all people involved.

So the answer to your question depends on what kind of users the web application(s?) built upon your service layer have and how many. And how much they wish to know about them. Can you perhaps trust Google / Facebook / Windows Live for authentication? Are the users already in an existing database within your domain? How much work will it take to maintain the user directories? Do your marketing people wish to send them emails regularly? Et cetera.

This is probably not just for the service layer's developers to decide, but something to discuss with people in the rest of your organisation.

If the benefits are not particularly big, the alternative is to simply keep these responsibilities at the web application's server. Each web application will have a good old ASP.Net membership database, it'll authenticate the user all by itself. When asking queries from the service layer, it'll present its web server certificate plus specify the user's name and type.

If the benefits are big enough, you can in principle use ADFS 2.0 for everything. It can also store external users nowadays and it's free if you already have Active Directory. Or the ThinkTecture 2.0 server that Ross recommends. It's easier to customize and perhaps your systems administrators and security folks will not be too enthusiastic about opening the firewall to the ADFS server.

Microsoft has [some good reads on WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx), in particular an [Overview of Claims-Based Architecture](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/D/0/7D0B5166-6A8A-418A-ADDD-95EE9B046994/Claims-Based%20Identity%20for%20Windows.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [identity server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/) as it can indeed handle this scenario.

The person who leads the project above has a great [pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=iac-wcf&highlight=) video on this exact scenario! You need to sign up to watch it, but they offer a free trial.

Basically you get a token from the identity provider (windows ADFS for the internal client, and what ever you decide for the external users). You will give this token to the federated gateway (identity server probably, but it could be Azure ACS). This will return an authentication token that you can then use with your service.